# debounce-throttle - Is there a cancel option with this package

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

https://www.npmjs.com/package/throttle-debounce

Is there a way to cancel the previous request while using this package - if a new request is made before debouce is executed?

```
this.ChangeBounce = debounce(700, this.ChangeBounce);
```

I am using this for live search api call and need to cancel the prev req as the api calls being made between debounce is causing an issue.

Comment: I don't think its the responsibility of the debounce, you should rather look into the package you are using for the API request

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout and clearTimeout:

```
let timer = null
this.ChangeBounce = () => {
  if (timer) {
    clearTimeout(timer)
    timer = null
  } else {
    timer = setTimeout(this.ChangeBounce, 700)
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't debounce the same as what you are trying to do